# geodjango difficulties with srid

Tags: spatialite, geodjango, srid

I'm trying to make geodjango app. I'm using SQLite and SpatialLite.
I want to add shops, and be able to sort them from closest to furthest from my location.

When in my model I have:

```
location = gis_models.PointField(srid=4326, blank=True, null=True)
```

then adding works, but **sorting by distance does not work**, and I get:

```
SQLite does not support linear distance calculations on geodetic coordinate systems.
```

When I have:

```
location = gis_models.PointField(srid=3857, blank=True, null=True)
```

than **adding does not work**, and sorting works, and I get:

```
geo_shop.location violates Geometry constraint [geom-type or SRID not allowed]
```

What do I do to make them both work at the same time?

Comment: What do you mean with "adding"? Adding a new point?

Comment: @yellowcap, yes, adding a new point

Comment: Could you show how exactly you are trying to add a point? Is it through the admin, or in a view/script? If your data has srid `4326`, then adding a point might throw an error because it has the wrong `sird`...